# Server 2008 freezes and forces reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have had a client of ours move over to server 2008. The transition went smoothly(this is a domain controller) and we had no issues. However, it seems that after about a week the operating system hangs.

The mouse and keyboard stop responding and a remote connection into the
system is not allowed.
The only way to correct the issue is to hard reboot the system.

I have not seen any events logged in the event viewer that provides any
relevant information.

Our antivirus is vipre enterprise but other than that we have pretty much standard installs other then our monitoring software which allows us to track the servers status at all times. The thing is, the server shows online and responds to pings but nothing else can connect.

Any ideas?

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard
OS Version:                6.0.6001 Service Pack 1 Build 6001
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Primary Domain Controller
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Original Install Date:     9/29/2008, 3:55:54 AM
System Boot Time:          9/12/2010, 3:02:35 AM
System Manufacturer:       HP
System Model:              ProLiant DL380 G5
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              2 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10 GenuineIn
tel ~2833 Mhz
                           [02]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10 GenuineIn
tel ~2833 Mhz
BIOS Version:              HP P56, 9/29/2008

Total Physical Memory:     12,285 MB
Available Physical Memory: 7,984 MB
Page File: Max Size:       30,359 MB
Page File: Available:      25,868 MB
Page File: In Use:         4,491 MB
Page File Location(s):     D:\pagefile.sys
Network Card(s):           1 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: HP NC373i Multifunction Gigabit Server Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection 2
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
```

Comment: Update all the drivers from HP yet?

Comment: I would add to Chris's question with the fact that there is a new BIOS firmware update 2010.04.26 (A), 17 Aug 2010.  I would start with updating drivers and firmware first.

Comment: emm that's a good point, I will roll out an update time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had symantec antivirus give me the same thing about once per month on a 2k8 server, shares all die and it's only pingable. Basically I think it killed all RPC and the server service.  They released a fix - you may wanna try your AV support and see if they've released a patch or are aware of it for their version.  Anyway, symantec was the only 3rd party software on the box and before I got the symantec patch I removed the AV and the system was flawless.

Comment: I've tried support and they claim it has nothing to do with their software. I suspected the active protection of VIPRE myself but hangs are so hard since they don't generate any kind of information relating to it.

Comment: Then, like our fine members above have recommended - I'd start updating drivers.  Locking up the mouse and keyboard is generally a world that bad drivers (especially video) play in from my experience.

Comment: I updated the drivers to max and it hasn't crashed yet, 
Thanks